# Why do these answers have the wrong time? How could they be posted before the question?

Tags: support, answers, timestamps, merged-questions

This image says it all:

[image]

The answerers are so lucky... Somehow they answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050415/update-database) 18 hours before it was even  asked... How did they do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This question was merged with another one**, asked 18 hours ago. Those people answered *that* question, and their answers simply got merged over into this one but kept the same time stamp.

A quick check of the [revisions history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7050415/revisions) confirms. It says:

> Post Merged from [stackoverflow.com/questions/7044330/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044330/updating-database-with-dropdown-value) by [Kev Ω♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419/kev)

That is, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044330/updating-database-with-dropdown-value) (10k only), posted 18 hours ago.

Comment: aah, I see it now: merged by Kev Ω♦ 19 mins ago

Answer (score 2):

There was another question that was a dupe asked by the same user. I closed as duplicate, merged then deleted the duplicate. That's why the times might be a bit odd.