# Why are answers much older than the question?

Tags: support, timestamps, merged-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do these answers have the wrong time? How could they be posted before the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102252/why-do-these-answers-have-the-wrong-time-how-could-they-be-posted-before-the-qu)

[Can code that is valid in both C and C++ produce different behavior when compiled in each language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12887700/476681)

The above question was asked on the 14th October 2012, and some answers are from 2009.

[image: question]

[image: answers]

Comment: duplicate of: [Why do these answers have the wrong time? How could they be posted before the question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102252/165773)

Comment: @gnat good catch. I haven't seen it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because the question was merged with an older question. Look under the question's revision history: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12887700/revisions

Comment: Yep. [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/18wUj.png) :)